# Rakudo (Perl6): What are the features that don’t yet work?

Tags: perl, raku, rakudo

Rakudo: Is there a place where all the features that don't yet work are listed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://rakudo.org/status shows a list of things, but it's hard to keep it up-to-date. The biggest things are probably threading, async IO (both due to Parrot lacking them). Some things are quite there, but have bugs (like traits).

Comment: when I click that, I get 404 - not found

Answer (score 5):

You can also listen to this interview on floss-weekly, dated October 29th, 2010:

Randal Schwartz interviewing Patrick Michaud, the current main developer of Rakudo.

I think he talks about what does not work in the latter half of the  >1hr interview

http://twit.tv/floss140

The file is audio only. And it certainly does not mention ALL features that do not work, but it provides some context.

Comment: Now, at the end of 2019, the Raku Programming Language (https://raku.org) basically supports all of the features promised, and then some.  The only big exception still, is the full use of macros.